# How to improve Quality of image while taking zoomin picture in Android xamarin

Tags: image, xamarin.android, pixel

I need to improve image quality, from low quality to high quality while zoomin picture, how to improve the quality of image while zoomin image in android xamarin. Is it possible to do this? I will really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

```
private void handleZoom(bool isZoomIn, global::Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
        {
            //camera.StopPreview();
            //  camera.Release();
            // camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
            global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
            if (parameters.IsZoomSupported)
            {
                int maxZoom = parameters.MaxZoom;
                int zoom = parameters.Zoom;

                if (isZoomIn && zoom < maxZoom)
                {
                    zoom++;
                }
                else if (zoom > 0)
                {
                    zoom--;
                }
                parameters.Zoom = zoom;
                camera.SetParameters(parameters);
                camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                PrepareAndStartCamera();
            }
            else
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "zoom not supported");
            }
        }
```

Comment: stillCaptureBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.JpegQuality, Java.Lang.Byte.ValueOf(90)); i cannot use like these but how to improve  normal camera api in android to improve the quality while zoomin the image

Comment: I would imagine you'd lose image quality regardless of what library you use. The more you zoom, the bigger your pixels become.